# Use smtp with php on one.com

Tags: php, email

I'm working on a website hosted by one.com, and I would use the function PHP "mail" to send email.

But nothing works. Do you know how to set SMTP? init_set doesn't work.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The One.com's support have just answered my question :

I must use a mail address linked with my one.com account, something like xxxx@mydomain.com, with this header :

```
$headers = 'From: xxxx@mydomain.com' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: xxxx@mydomain.com' . "\r\n" .
```